# Gradle project inside Gradle project?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

So I have a library project that is common to all of my android projects. This project is split into 2 modules, 1 of which is the Java specific module where I put re-usable components specific to java, and the other is the android module where I put re-usable android specific components. The android module also requires the java module, so the android project compiles the java module in it's build.gradle file with `compile project(':javalibrary')`. I have a standalone eclipse project setup to make edits to the library all by itself. Everything compiles and works fine so far. I can run tests, etc just fine.

I add the entire library project to my git repo as a git submodule, and then I'd like to be able to add the android library project to the build of my android project, and the java library project where applicable. **This is where I start to have problems.**

I end up with a directory structure like this:

```
-/AndroidProject
  build.gradle
  settings.gradle
  -/library
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
    -/androidlibrary
      build.gradle
    -/javalibrary
      build.gradle
  -/AndroidAppModule
    build.gradle
```

So in the AndroidProject settings.gradle I add `include ':library:androidlibrary', ':library:javalibrary'`

And then for the AndroidAppModule build.gradle dependencies I call `compile project(':library:androidlibrary')`

**I'll get a build error at this point** I'll try and build, and I'll get a build error because the library android project can't find the library java project. So I can go into the androidlibrary build.gradle and change `compile project(':javalibrary')` to `compile project(':library:javalibrary')` and it will resolve all build conflicts and work perfectly.

Then when I go back to the intellij project that I make edits to the the library project to do an edit or what not, it won't build any more because the android library is then looking to /library/javaproject when really it should just be looking to /javaproject (because the /library directory only exists when it's added as a git submodule)

So I need some way of standardizing this, so that the entire library project directory will see itself as it's own root directory, or some other clever way of doing this. How would I go about this?

Comment: It's been 4 years, did you figure it out or switch back to maven?

Answer (score 0):

If you use [group](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project%3agroup) property you should be able to name your libraries and refer to them independently of directory structure.

Comment: I've come back to this several times over the past few days, and I can't figure out how to apply your answer. Can you be more specific please?

Comment: I've tried to find examples of this being applied and failed. The documentation just isn't very specific. Where should I place this property, and then what file should I be trying to import? Should I be skipping the /library/build.gradle?